# Update database within job to accomplish progress bar

Tags: apex, job

I have this job:

```
public class MyJob implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts {

   // ...

   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<Phone_Numbers__c> numbers) {
      // the scope (numbers) is the queued numbers added before
      for (Phone_Numbers__c phoneNumber : numbers) {
          // do stuff with number (update its jobStatus)
          Database.update(phoneNumber);
      }
   }

   @AuraEnabled // this is in a controller class but I left here for simplicity
   public static List<Phone_Numbers__c> getNumbers() {
    return [
        SELECT id, name, job_Id__c, flow_Id__c, job_Status__c, job_Type__c
        FROM Phone_Numbers__c LIMIT 5000
    ];
   }
   // ...
}
```

It end ups with an infinite cycle, possibly because **I'm updating the table that I'm iterating upon (I tried updating another object and it does not work either; it seems we can't update stuff within the cycle; btw.. this table is a custom setting list - historical reasons).**

But I need that "inside forEach update" because I'm exposing that table with an `@AuraEnabled` to display a progress bar.
If I extract the `Database.update` outside of the cycle it works but it does not update the progress bar (which makes sense)...

This is a the GUI code that polls the server to know the current job status:

```
handleFlowStatusChangedHelper: function(component, event) {
    const self = this
    var timer = window.setInterval(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            const isJobRunning = component.get('c.getNumbers'); // check @AuraEnabled above
            isJobRunning.setCallback(component, function(resp) {
                if (resp.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
                    const isJobRunning = resp.getReturnValue().find(function(el) { return el.jobStatus === 'QUEUED' });
                    if (!isJobRunning) window.clearInterval(timer); // if the server says no job is running
                    // removed the code.. it was just an update of the progress bar value based on resp.getReturnValue() which contains the list of numbers and their states
                    // update progress bar 
                }
                if (resp.getState() === 'ERROR') console.error(resp.getError());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(isJobRunning);
        }), 700
    );
},
```

The Aura code of the progress bar:

```
<div class="slds-progress-bar slds-docked-composer__body" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0" role="progressbar" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <span aura:id="publishing-state-value" class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="{! 'width:' + v.currentPercentage + '%' }" />
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How does your asynchronous batch job affect a synchronous UI for the user? Additionally, how are we supposed to help you improve, or even understand your UI code, without seeing it?

Comment: because the UI is polling the server about that table. ok I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can you poll the `JobItemsProcessed` and `TotalJobItems` fields on the `AsyncApexJob` record representing this batch job to obtain its progress, rather than trying to signal from the async process to the UI?

Comment: good point. I'll try that!

Comment: @DavidReed Sounds like an answer to me! Id vote for it if you posted it

Comment: Because of database isolation, the DML inside the loop idea wouldn't work anyways, because the records can't be queried outside the current transaction until they are committed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to poll based on individual record updates (which, additionally, will reduce your possible batch size and overall performance), try polling the `JobItemsProcessed` and `TotalJobItems` fields on the `AsyncApexJob` that represents this batch process. You'll get back progress information at the granularity of your batch size - for example, if you are processing 1000 records in batches of 200, you'll get back progress in steps of 20% at 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000 records processed.

Comment: thanks for the help.
`TotalJobItems` has the number of jobs which is `1`.. not the number of numbers queued within the job (at `start` job method) :/

Comment: That's the number of batches you're processing, which will depend on the number of records and your specified batch size.

Comment: I specified 10 as the batch size. so the batch size is always 1 because the numbers are less than 10. But I need the total numbers as a whole: the count equivalent do the query within `start` method.

Comment: Why do you need an item-by-item progress bar for a batch job processing fewer than 10 records? You're going to sacrifice a lot of performance if you build your solution around that requirement. You *can* set your batch size to 1, but I don't understand why you'd want to do that.

Comment: the requirement is "the user can ask to activate several numbers at the same time (e.g. 20); that would trigger a job with to activate those numbers (using an external API); he wants to check the progress of that job to know how many numbers are activated already."
are you suggesting this should not be a job?

Comment: I don't think a batch job is ideally suited for this request. I also think this request is not something that is idiomatic on the Salesforce platform. If it's non-negotiable and the number of records affected is always relatively small, I'd probably try dispatching each individual request from JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: good point. it would not support the user refreshing the page and/or really long activations. but I could have a database object to hold the requests, if that is really needed.